# Windows XP/Windows 7 and Windows Servers login page

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, login-control

I would like to have a windows form application to popup right before when the user enters his or her windows credentials. If the validation in that particular windows form is successful then I want to let the user enter his or her windows credentials. How can I programmatically in C# do that in Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, and Windows servers like 2003 and 2008.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) article describes what you need to do to customize the windows logon experience for Windows Vista+ versions of Windows.

For pre-Vista releases, you may want to look into implementing a [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) plugin.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

That would mean bypassing the Window login system, which is not possible. Otherwise anyone could pop up a fake dialog that looks like the regular login page and steal credentials.